# Zeroes of Complex Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-writing, roots

Consider two complex functions $f$ and $f\prime$, each holomorphic in some domain $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}$. Denote the set of zeroes of $f$ in $\Omega$ by $Z$ and the set of zeroes of $f\prime$ in $\Omega$ by $Z\prime$. Then does there exist some function $g$ that is holomorphic in $\Omega$ with zeroes in $\Omega$ precisely at the points of $Z\cap Z\prime$? That is, $g(z) = 0$ for $z\in\Omega$ if and only if $f(z) = f\prime(z) = 0$.

Intuitively it seems like this should be possible. If we treat $f$ and $f\prime$ as real functions, then the function $g(x) = f(x)^2 + f\prime(x)^2$ would meet the requirement. But this doesn't work for complex numbers. For a counterexample, let $f(z) = ai \neq 0$ and $g(z) = -ai \neq 0$. Then $f(z)^2 = -a^2$, and $f\prime(z)^2 = a^2$, so there exists $z$ such that $g(z) = 0$ when $z\neq 0$.

So is such a function $g$ possible, with the constraint of being holomorphic in $\Omega$? And is there an explicit construction for such a function? And if not, what would a proof that this is not possible look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any set of points without accumulation points there is some holomorphic function whose zeros are those points. This is the so called Weierstrass Theorem. Since $f$ and $f'$ are holomorphic, the sets $Z$ and $Z'$ don't have accumulation points, so the same is true for $Z \cap Z'$

Comment: I haven't heard of the Weierstrass Theorem, but a quick Google search reveals a lot of different results, such as a Weierstrass Factorization Theorem, Stone-Weirestrass Theorem, Bolzano Weirestrass Theorem. Is there a different search term I could use to learn more about this theorem?

Comment: @MathRules Read the chapter 'Zeros of holomorphic functions' in Rudin's RCA.